# PASS and Log HTML Message after succeessful execution of test case

Tags: robotframework

When a test case in Robotframework FAILs I am able to log "Test Message" in report with FAIL keyword:

```
FAIL     *HTML* Log Link : <a href="data.txt">Data</a>
```

But how can I log the same on case of test PASS case criteria, I am not sure but should we use "Pass Execution" keyword - it states - Skips rest of the current test, setup, or teardown with PASS status - but I have teardown steps - so should we make use of Pass Execution keyword in test case body.

Log to Console logs only to standard output and is not captured in "Message" report.html while FAIL *msg* gets displayed in "Message"

Please let me know how to use PASS with message with just stating that the test cases was success and complete its teardown

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `log` keyword? Why does that not work for you?

Comment: Log has levels and it can be set as NONE or needs to be reset once my test case execution is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure but should we use "Pass Execution" keyword - it states - Skips rest of the current test, setup, or teardown with PASS status - but I have teardown steps - so should we make use of Pass Execution keyword in the test case body.

If you use [Pass Execution](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Pass%20Execution) in the body of a test case, your teardown steps will still run. The documentation is trying to point out that if you use `Pass Execution` inside a teardown, the teardown will stop at the point that you call the keyword.

You can see this with a very simple example. Even though the following test calls `Pass execution`, both the suite teardown and test teardown will add messages to the log.

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Teardown   log  the suite teardown was called

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    [Teardown]  log  the test teardown was called

    Should be equal  test  test
    Pass execution  Looking good Bill Ray!
```

[image: log.html excerpt]

If you want to explicitly set the test message, you can use the built-in keyword
[Set test message](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Message). It will change the test message for a passing test.

```
*** Test cases ***
Example
    Should be equal  test  test
    Set test message  Looking good Billy Ray!
```

Comment: Thanks - I have attached the expected output - you can see the HTML link "Log" after status "PASS" - to give user an easy way to access the Test Log - this was achieved with PASS EXECUTION tag and I could not achieve the same with Log tag